# Python Pandas - get oldest data in dataframe and ignore None types when searching?

Tags: python, pandas

im trying to get the oldest date in a data frame and I have seen its possible with the below:-

```
min(s2s_vpn_data['LastPollTime'])
```

sample dataframe below:

```
>>> s2s_vpn_data
   id  device name       public_ip     upload                LastPollTime NodeID   download status                          connected_time
0   1  XXXX   XXXX         2.2.2.2   7.48 Bit  2018-08-30 15:13:02.900000   1782   7.48 Bit   True  1 Months, 2 Days, 19 Hours, 25 Minutes
1   3  XXXX   XXXX         3.3.3.3  23.46 KiB  2018-08-30 15:10:26.900000   1782  27.31 PiB   True  1 Months, 2 Days, 19 Hours, 25 Minutes
2   4  XXXX   test         1.1.1.1       None                        None   None       None   None                                    None
>>> type(s2s_vpn_data.ix[0]["LastPollTime"])
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

however as I have a type as None I am seeing the error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

is there a way to ignore None types when searching ideally, I should just get the below returned

```
2018-08-30 15:10:26.900000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop the None when doing your min:

```
s2s_vpn_data['LastPollTime'].dropna().min()
```

Answer (score 1):

If the series (column) contains both datetimes and None's, the dtype of the series is likely actually `object`. Use `pd.to_datetime` to convert all of the types to valid datetime/Timestamp objects. This will convert your None values to `NaT` automatically, which will then be ignored when using the `.min` method:

```
df["LastPollTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["LastPollTime"])
df["LastPollTime"].min()
```